What percent of the time does an absorbing Markov chain does not contain $x$ state
I'm currently doing an experiment with absorbing Markov chains, and what I'm trying to do is calculate what percent of the time an absorbing Markov chain won't contain a certain state. To better illustrate my example, let us take this absorbing Markov chain with transition matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix}
0.864 & 0.04 & 0.096 & 0\\
0 & 0.904 & 0 & 0.096\\
0 & 0 & 0.96 & 0.04\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$
I'm not sure how to label rows and columns, but let's call each state (in order):
$p_{\emptyset},\: p_1, \:p_2,\: p_{1, 2}$
When we use the formula in the Wikipedia article to find the expected number of steps before being absorbed, or
$t:=N1,$
We get:
$\begin{bmatrix}
28.064\\
10.41667\\
25\end{bmatrix}$
or approximately $28$ steps before being absorbed assuming we start in state $p_{\emptyset}.$ What I want to find is what percent of the time or for how many steps the chain is not in the state $p_1$ and therefore event $1$ (the $1$ in $p_1$) has not happened yet.
What I'm thinking of is using the fundamental matrix $N$ to solve for the expected number of visits to each transient state, but after thinking about it a bit more, I realize I have no idea what I'm doing. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

The way Markov chains are defined, the chain will spend $100%$ of its time in state ${1,2}$, since (with probability 1) it will spend only finitely many steps in the other states, and infinitely many steps in the absorbing state. But if you define $X$ to be the hitting time for the state ${1,2}$, and $Y$ to be the hitting time for the pair of states $1$ and ${1,2}$, then you can find the expected value of $\frac{Y}{X}$. Is this what you want? (Warning: this is in general not the same as the expected value of $Y$ divided by the expected value of $X$.)

Sorry, I was thinking of something else. I edited it to be correct, but what I want to calculate is percent of the time (before it is absorbed) that the Markov chain does not spend in state $p_1,$ or how long it will spend in either $p_{\emptyset}$ or $p_2$

If the trajectory is, say, $\emptyset \to \emptyset \to 1 \to {1,2}$, where it is absorbed, did the Markov chain spend $\frac13$ or $\frac14$ of that time in state $1$?

I'm fairly sure it's $\frac{1}{4},$ since with the same logic using my example Markov chain it takes an average of $28$ steps before it is absorbed, and since that is our denominator I'd assume it includes the absorbed state.

I think that's the wrong type of logic to use - you shouldn't ask "what kind of answer will this method give me?" but "what kind of answer do I need for my application?"

Well, that is the preferable outcome, and based on that I am able to answer your previous question.

In general, expected values of ratios are difficult to calculate. Working with the absorbing Markov chain, there is a standard way to calculate the expected number of steps until absorption, and probably we can also calculate the expected number of steps in state $1$ without too much trouble, either. However, the expected fraction of time (until absorption) spent in state $1$ is not the ratio between these quantities, because they are not independent: maybe in cases where the Markov chain visits state $1$, it is also more likely to be absorbed quickly!
However, there is a way to compute a closely related expected value of a ratio in an ergodic Markov chain. Ergodic Markov chains don't have absorbing states, but they do have limiting probabilities. The limiting probability $\pi_x$ is the long-term fractions of time spent in state $x$. It can be found by solving a system of equations. Specifically, if $A$ is the transition matrix, and $\vec \pi$ is the row vector of probabilities, we use the equations

$\vec \pi A = \vec \pi$ (or $\vec \pi (A - I) = \vec 0$), indicating that the limiting probability is a fixed point of multiplication by the transition matrix, together with
$\vec \pi \cdot \vec 1 = 1$: the limiting probabilities add up to $1$.

For more details, see for instance section 11.2.6 of Pishro-Nik's Introduction to Probability, Statistics, and Random Processes.
Why are these relevant? Because of a nice characterization of limiting probabilities via excursions. An excursion from a state $x$ is a span of time from the point that the Markov chain leaves state $x$ until the next time it returns to state $x$. The nice thing about excursions is that an excursion observes each state with exactly its limiting probability! More precisely:

Fact. In an ergodic Markov chain, the expected number of times that state $y$ is visited on an excursion out of state $x$ is $\frac{\pi_y}{\pi_x}$.

To make use of this: given an absorbing Markov chain, we modify it by making the absorbing state $x$ a copy of our initial state. Here's how this goes in the given example:
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
 & \emptyset & 1 & 2 & \{1,2\} \\
\hline
\emptyset & 0.864 & 0.04 & 0.096 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0.904 & 0 & 0.096 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0.96 & 0.04 \\
\{1,2\} & 0.864 & 0.04 & 0.096 & 0 
\end{array}
Solving for the limiting probabilities in this example gives us $$\pi_\emptyset \approx 0.226 \qquad \pi_1 \approx 0.109 \qquad \pi_2 \approx 0.629 \qquad \pi_{\{1,2\}} \approx 0.0356.$$ Actually, one thing we can quickly get from here is that $\frac{1}{\pi_{\{1,2\}}}$ is the average length of an excursion - and therefore the average number of steps to absorption. (Here, it gives us approximately $28.0637$, which we already knew.) But we can go further and compute $\frac{\pi_1}{\pi_{\{1,2\}}} \approx 3.0637$. This is the number of times state $1$ is visited on an excursion in the modified Markov chain - or on a path to absorption in the original Markov chain.

Sorry, I'm still mostly incompetent with other Markov chains that aren't absorbing. How did you calculate the limiting probability? Also, what is the $\pi$ notation?

Sorry, I didn't include those details, because in my mind, the limiting probability is the very most basic fundamental thing that people do with Markov chains, and absorbing probabilities are much fancier stuff. I'll edit to add more details about it!
